# Program immediately jumps to the else clause in my code

Tags: python, if-statement

I just started learning python. I'm building an adventure type game right now as my first project, but unfortunately one of my if statements (line 12-18) doesn't work. If anyone could point out the problem to me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
print("Hello and welcome to the Virgin Club Adventure Game! The main objective of this game is to befriend every "
      "member of the Virgin Club. \n But before we start...")
user_name = input("Please tell us your name:")
user_age = int(input("And your age:"))
friendship_points: str(2)

if user_age >= 13:
    print("Great! You're old enough to play the game.")
    start = input("Shall we begin? (yes/no) ")
    ***if start == "yes":
        left_or_right = input("A path diverges before you. \n To your left, the path leads to a small forest in the "
                              "woods. \n To the right, the path leads to a bustling city. \n Where do you want to go? "
                              "(left/right)")
        if left_or_right == "left":
            print("You head down the path and towards the cottage.")
        elif left_or_right == "right":
            print("You know no one in the city. You look around for a familiar face, to no avail. A car hits you as "
                  "you try to cross the road. You die alone, with no virgins beside you. \n Game Over!")
        else:
            print("Choose an actual path, you &*(%!")
    else:
        print("Alright then. Come back when you have better taste!")***
else:
    print("You're too young to play. Scram, ankle biter!")
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? What inputs are you entering?

Comment: well i've tested it out, the only answers you can put are yes and no. but even though i type in yes in the input, the program doesn't progress to the next step.it just jumps to the else clause.

Comment: Are you typing in exactly `yes`, and not `Yes` or `YES` or something like that?

Comment: Make sure you aren't typing any spaces before or after "yes" as well. The code you have posted works as expected.

Comment: ah, thats where the problem was. i was adding a space before the "yes" input. thank you so much for pointing it out @chepner! thats a huge headache gone. and thank you @jasonharper for your comment as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, the input was actually the string  `yes` (with a leading space). If you wish to handle that in your code, use the `strip` method before comparing the input to the target string:

```
if start.strip() == "yes":
```

`strip` (with no argument) will return a new string that lacks any leading or trailing whitespace from the original string.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks alright and performs the task you want it to do. Simply remove the 3 asterisks on lines 17 and 29. At `***if start == "yes":` and

```
else:
        print("Alright then. Come back when you have better taste!")***
```

So the final result should look like this:

```
print("Hello and welcome to the Virgin Club Adventure Game! The main objective of this game is to befriend every "
      "member of the Virgin Club. \n But before we start...")
user_name = input("Please tell us your name:")
user_age = int(input("And your age:"))
friendship_points: str(2)

if user_age >= 13:
    print("Great! You're old enough to play the game.")
    start = input("Shall we begin? (yes/no) ")
    if start == "yes":
        left_or_right = input("A path diverges before you. \n To your left, the path leads to a small forest in the "
                              "woods. \n To the right, the path leads to a bustling city. \n Where do you want to go? "
                              "(left/right)")
        if left_or_right == "left":
            print("You head down the path and towards the cottage.")
        elif left_or_right == "right":
            print("You know no one in the city. You look around for a familiar face, to no avail. A car hits you as "
                  "you try to cross the road. You die alone, with no virgins beside you. \n Game Over!")
        else:
            print("Choose an actual path, you &*(%!")
    else:
        print("Alright then. Come back when you have better taste!")
else:
    print("You're too young to play. Scram, ankle biter!")
```

This runs as it should.

Comment: I think OP has done that intentionally to tell where does OP get stuck

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, didn't even consider it, but that's weird cos it runs as it should.

Comment: okay, now this is weird... i dont have those 3 astericks in my python code. i checked just now, and the code was exactly like you put it as above. i dont mean to discredit your help. thank you for your time.

Comment: when i pick "left" as an input, my code still prints out "Choose an actual path, you &^%!" sigh

Comment: When I pick 'left' as an input mine prints out "You head down the path and towards the cottage.". Maybe a screen shot of your code instead would help clarify things.

Comment: Never mind, i found out that i was adding a space between my inputs as answers. man i never knew spaces were so important. thank you so much for you time though. have a good day/night.